# 5 Day Rolling Returns SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to show a 5 day rolling return for a given set of stocks over a long period of time, and then isolate which ones had 5 day periods of -10% and when. I was able to do this with the following code, but it takes way too long to run to be allowed in my system, so I need a more efficient way. If I were able to run a newer version than 2005, I'd use

```
EXP(SUM(LOG(1+Return_Value)) OVER(  PARTITION BY Reference_Number ORDER BY 
Reference_Number, Return_Date ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ))-1 
AS Rolling_Return
```

to geometrically combine the values I need to combine for each date and stock. Thought that was going to work great until I discovered my 2005 version of SQL Server doesn't like part of the OVER clause. Here's the slow version:

```
SELECT  r1.*,
    r2.Return_Value2,
    r2.Row2,
    r3.Return_Value3,
    r3.Row3,
    r4.Return_Value4,
    r4.Row4,
    r5.Return_Value5,
    r5.Row5,
    ((1+r1.Return_Value)*(1+r2.Return_Value2)*(1+r3.Return_Value3)*(1+r4.Return_Value4)*(1+r5.Return_Value5)-1) AS Five_Day_Return  
FROM    
(
    SELECT  Reference_Number,
            Return_Date,
            Return_Value,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Reference_Number ORDER BY Reference_Number, Return_Date) AS Row1
    FROM    #returns
)   r1
INNER   JOIN
(
    SELECT  Reference_Number,
            Return_Date,
            Return_Value AS Return_Value2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY r.Reference_Number ORDER BY Reference_Number, Return_Date) AS Row2
    FROM    #returns
)   r2
ON      r1.Reference_Number = r2.Reference_Number
AND     r1.Row1 = r2.Row2 + 1
INNER   JOIN
(
    SELECT  Reference_Number,
            Return_Date,
            Return_Value AS Return_Value3,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Reference_Number ORDER BY Reference_Number, Return_Date) AS Row3
    FROM    #returns
)   r3
ON      r1.Reference_Number = r3.Reference_Number
AND     r1.Row1 = r3.Row3 + 2
INNER   JOIN
(
    SELECT  Reference_Number,
            Return_Date,
            Return_Value AS Return_Value4,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Reference_Number, ORDER BY Reference_Number Return_Date) AS Row4
    FROM    #returns
)   r4
ON      r1.Reference_Number = r4.Reference_Number
AND     r1.Row1 = r4.Row4 + 3
INNER   JOIN
(
    SELECT  Reference_Number,
            Return_Date,
            Return_Value AS Return_Value5,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Reference_Number ORDER BY Reference_Number, Return_Date) AS Row5
    FROM    #returns
)   r5
ON      r1.Reference_Number = r5.Reference_Number
AND     r1.Row1 = r5.Row5 + 4
WHERE   ((1+r1.Return_Value)*(1+r2.Return_Value2)*(1+r3.Return_Value3)* 
(1+r4.Return_Value4)*(1+r5.Return_Value5)-1) <= -.1
ORDER   BY r1.Return_Date
```

This code gets me to where I need to be, but I test ran it for just 1 security and it was way too slow even just looking at 1 Reference_Number. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your query.  The canonical way of expressing this without window functions is:

```
select r.*,
       (select exp(sum(log(1 + r2.return_value)))
        from (select top (5) r2.return_value
              from #returns r2
              where r2.Reference_Number = r.Reference_Number and
                    r2.Return_Date <= r.Return_Date
              order by r2.Return_Date desc
             ) r2
       ) as rolling_5
from #returns r;
```

An index on `#returns(Reference_Number, Return_Date, return_value)` would definitely help performance.  If that is not enough, I would suggest that you upgrade to a supported product.  SQL Server 2005 support ended years ago on April 12, 2016.

Comment: This works! Way simpler than I was trying to do. Still pretty new to coding. Wish upgrading SQL was up to me but it isn't.

Comment: `"I would suggest that you upgrade to a supported product. SQL Server 2005 support ended years ago on April 12, 2016."` >> I don't think this can be stressed enough. When I see questions about anything less than SQL 2K5, the problem isn't really that there's a question of how to do something. The problem is that with just about any software that old, there are likely much larger issues than haven't been realized yet.

Comment: @Donnie Again my 2 cents: the upgrade may not be up to you, but it definitely impacts you, and it's a major company issue just waiting to happen. An upgrade from SQL 2012 may be hard to justify, but something that many versions back has plenty of easily findable, provable and demonstrable justifications.

Comment: Hey I mean I'm with you, I'll mention it to my boss. Given the nature of our business and the scale of it, you'd think it's something we'd be on top of. Oddly it seems like some of our databases sit in 2008 and some sit in 2005.

Comment: 2008 and 2008R2 will reach End of Support next year. As Gordon pointed out, 2005 ended a couple of years ago. There was a huge jump in functionality from 2005 to 2008. Even more so for more recent versions. And MS SQL isn't cheap. I do feel for you. Being stuck with any old technology can really suck. :-/ But just to pitch your boss one of the biggest justifications for some sort of upgrade: it's still cheaper to upgrade than to get breached.